# Probability Theory: universe-less vision of Jaynes in his book Probability Theory?

Tags: probability-theory, soft-question

Is the "universe" $\Omega$ in probabilities self-contained or can we find events that go beyond $\Omega$ ?

I know that the measure theory approach of probabilities requires that $p(\Omega)=1$, but after all isn't measure theory just a tool, part of the wider picture of Probability Theory?

I ask because I am currently reading Jaynes, [*Probability Theory: the Logic of Science*](http://www.med.mcgill.ca/epidemiology/hanley/bios601/GaussianModel/JaynesProbabilityTheory.pdf) and he hasn't spoken yet about a "universe" (I am about to reach chapter $3$). In the first two chapters, he defines the desiderata (kind of axioms) to which a machine taking decisions about plausibilities should obey, then he derivied from these desiderata the product and sum rule and he finally derived $p(A_i)= 1/n$ for "equiprobable" (that's not the term he uses) events. He even solved the classical "Bernoulli urn" (three red balls, seven black balls).

Never has he used the term universe, or anything that would look like that.

He only considers $p(A|C)$, in which $A$ is an event whose intersection with $C$ is not necessarily equal to $A$.

That leads me to think that, there is no such a thing as a *universe*, but only events ($A$, $C$ for example) which satisfy $p(A|C) + p(\bar A |C) = 1$.

All of this is said in the context of Probability Theory.

PS: I am also dubitative about how we could say: "let all the possibilities in the physical universe (and beyond) be represented by $\Omega$". It seems to me that we could always find an event that lives (at least partly) outside of this $\Omega$.

Comment: As I don't have this particular text available, I don't know what the goal is.  It *sounds* to me like the author is very intentionally avoiding a discussion of "universes", and that in their exposition, the notion of a "universe" is not all that relevant.  In more measure-theoretic settings, the "universe" will be a mathematical abstraction:  the underlying set of a measure space which carries a probability measure.  In neither case, however, does this say much about the "real world"---we are talking about mathematical abstractions.

Comment: Besides an example of a probability textbook which does not speak about a "universe", can you give us an example of a one which *does*?

Comment: @LeeMosher Yes of course, I don't remember the title (something like "Introduction to Probabilities"), by Ross.

Comment: Also, one thing to keep in mind: mathematical terminology rarely (never?) comports exactly and precisely with common language definitions of the terminology. Ideally the terminology is chosen to match one's intuition in at least a limited way, but it's unreasonable to expect an exact match.

Comment: Anyway, the way I understand the usage of the term "universe" in probability theory is that it is the set of all outcomes in an experiment. An event is a (certain kind of) subset of the universe; the probability function $p$ assigns a number $p(A)$ to each event; and certain axioms must hold, one of which is that if $U$ denotes the universe then $p(U)=1$. The intuition is that $U$ is the universe of all possible outcomes for *this particular experiment*. Every different experiment has its own universe of outcomes.

Comment: If you had an $\Omega$ that somehow included "all the possibilities in the physical universe (and beyond)", how could an event be even partly outside this universe? Wouldn't it just be part of the "beyond"? The actual problem is that this $\Omega$ isn't a mathematical object and we can't use it in mathematical probability.

Comment: I have not read much from this peculiar author E.T. Jaynes and probably never will. Looking a bit at his Appendix it becomes apparent that he abhors the measure theoretic approach to probability as we know it from A.N. Kolmogorov. I am not surprised that in his first few chapters he seems to avoid talking about $\Omega$ and even more so about $\sigma$-algebras.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have taken a glance at the document that you link in your question. Here are some of my thoughts (some pertaining directly to the book, later some more general things).

**The Book**

Before I go any farther, note that the author says himself in Appendix A that everything that they do is equivalent to the version of probability theory with a universe. Without going into the details on whether that is correct or not, the authors seems to imply that their description is only philosophically different.

The next point is that the book clearly only cares about probabilities in discrete contexts. If I understand it correctly, the author comes from  some machine learning community, where this point of view is very understandable. I want to note for completeness that continuous "random variables" (he is careful not to call them that way) are treated at some point, but only by looking at the discrete events $\{ X \leq q\}$.

If one were to really care about continuous probabilities, the first thing one needs to make sure of is that one does not run into the problem with [Vitali sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set). In the language of the book: consider

B = I throw a dart onto the interval $[0,1]$

A = The dart hits one of the elements of the Vitali set $V$

Now, what is $A\vert B$? In the context of the book, both $A$ and $B$ are reasonable assertion (with the only exception that no dart is infinitesimally small, but that is why I say "If one were to really care about continuous probabilities"). Classical probability theory tells us that one **cannot** give a probability to this event! It is simply not possible. From the standpoint of the book, however, I do not really see why this should not be possible. So is there an inconsistency? Or do I just miss something? Both are possible, but so far I would remain cautious until this has been clarified.

So all in all I see two options: 1) the theory is one to one equivalent to the classical theory as stated in Appendix A and then it is just a philosophical difference for which I do not really care, when I am doing math; or 2) it is not equivalent and there are actually some problems (see Vitali sets) in which case I would prefer to use classical probability theory.

**Some general thoughts**

I personally very much like to think about probability theory as an information theory (in this sense very much like the author of this book!).
I do think, however, that one should make something very clear: **probabilities are a model and do not represent reality**. The first implication is that your point in the P.S. is not relevant to the mathematics. There is no model in the world that represents reality exactly. Instead, they simplify reality and presume many things (some of which we know to be false!). In this sense, we may very well assume such a universe to exist as long as we get a model a) with which we can do maths and b) that gives good predictions.
Whether we are ok with these simplifications and assumptions from a philosophical point of view is a completely different problem.

Now let me get to why I actually really like the idea of a universe. Consider the example of a die. The first time one encounters this experiments, we are told that the universe is $\Omega = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$, including all possible outcomes of this experiments. I do, however, from a philosophical point of view, agree with the point that you make in the P.S. There are a lot of events happening that are not part of the universe. And here comes the ingenuity of probability theory. If you have taken enough classes in abstract probability theory, you will note that most of the time, the universe (or better: probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$) is never specified and remains always abstract. The very practical reason is that they simply become to complicated to write them down explicitly (some of the are even impossible to write down explicitly, because they are constructed through the axiom of choice!). But it has also a very nice philosophical interpretation: if we assume for a second that the universe of all possible outcomes does indeed exist, then it is not possible for us to write it down explicitly. Instead, we are only able to see how the randomness on the universe (given through $\mathbb P$) is transported to things that we may observe. In this setting, the example from the die is as follows: there is some abstract probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ containing in particular as subsets all the events of throwing the die in some particular way, and a random variable $Die: \Omega \rightarrow \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$ that observes the number of the die once it has stopped moving. And because we are modelling it in a symmetric way, we impose that $\mathbb P(Die = i) = \frac{1}{6}$ for every $i=1,\dots,6$. This is also the reason, why I do not like the name "random variable": it is neither random nor variable. Instead, I prefer to term "observable" as it describes how we observe the randomness. But this discussion is old as time and perhaps not too relevant to this question.

The important thing here is that the "universe" is not an important object in probability theory. In school, kids are told that the universe contains every possible outcome and is always written down explicitly, but this very concrete view gets lost when going to more abstract things. Instead, the universe is some very abstract thing that simply guarantees that we can do mathematics. In some sense, this is a very ingenuous trick to say "As mathematicians, we have no idea (and do not care) what probabilities really are. For this reason, we stuff everything in some abstract object which then can be analyzed and interpreted by philosophers."

I hope this did help a bit.

Comment: Nice answer. Just a few remarks: a) Not sure if we can safely say that [E.T. Jaynes (1922-1998)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edwin_Thompson_Jaynes) comes from a machine learning community. b) I cannot help thinking that Jaynes' appendix is quite polemic against measure theoretic probability but imho the book does not really offer a convincing rigorous alternative. Like with quantum mechanics one might just follow the mantra "shut up and calculate".

Comment: You may very well be correct on a), it was just a hunch which might come from the statistical inference stuff he speaks about. For b), I completely agree ^^ @KurtG.

Comment: @MushuNrek Isn't there (at least in theory) a third option, which is that classical probability theory and E.T. Jaynes probability theory prove common results, but that there are problems that E.T. Jaynes can't solve (that classical probability theory can) e.g. Vitali set and on the other hand problems that E.T. Jaynes can solve (that classical probability theory can't) ?

Comment: E.T. Jaynes claims that : "This enables us to formulate and solve
many problems – particularly the so-called ‘ill posed’ problems and ‘generalized inverse’
problems – that would be considered outside the scope of probability theory according to
the Kolmogorov system"

Comment: @niobium Well... If it is equivalent to the classical theory (as he seems to claim), then no. It is not possible that some parts work in one and other in the other theory. If it is not equivalent, then maybe. The problem is that everything he does seems to me super vague and difficult to check rigorously. But as I said: I have only glanced at the book and will probably not read it in the future, so it might very well be that I am missing something important. As to the quote: I have seen it, but not immediately found an example. Can you provide one?

Comment: @niobium Perhaps what they meant was that there are some problems that are easier to interpret in their framework? Or better to model?